# Can a set containing non-standard elements only, have a legal set formation?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Is it possible to form a set that contains only non-standard elements legally? A legal set formation means that only internal formulas can be used to form the set.

Here's what I thought: A set containing non-standard elements must be a non-standard set. Otherwise, by transfer principle, it has to be empty. Thus it can't be uniquely described by internal mathematics. It can't take the form as $\{x : A(x)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set containing a single non-standard element is perfectly legal.

If the "standard" predicate cannot be used, then translated into NSA you can only define sets that are natural extensions of real sets $X$.  The natural extension of the empty set $X=\emptyset$ is still empty.  If $X$ is inhabited, then its natural extension, which contains all the elements of $X$, will necessarily contain standard elements.

Comment: Similarly, an interval both of whose endpoints are unlimited positive numbers is legal but contains no standard points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide an explicit construction, which is only based on axioms of set theory?

Comment: To define such interval, shouldn't we define the two endpoints first? But I can't come up with a method to define an unlimited number without using the predicate "standard".

Comment: Thank you. I have to take some time to grok your argument.